# XMLHttpRequest doesn't work in asynchronus mode when my php code use DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile

Tags: javascript, php, xmlhttprequest, domdocument

I have a php script that return me a string after parsing a DOM from an html file.

parserFunctions.php (I just have displayed usefull functions):

```
<?php
function initPagesToParse($Path){
    define('MESSAGES_BY_PAGE', 20);
    $Docs[0] = new DOMDocument();
    $Docs[0]->loadHTMLFile($Path);
    $numberOfPages = getMessageNumber($Docs[0]) / MESSAGES_BY_PAGE;
    if($numberOfPages > 1){
        for($i = 1; $i < $numberOfPages; $i++){
            $startPost = $i * MESSAGES_BY_PAGE;
            $Docs[$startPost] = new DOMDocument();
            $Docs[$startPost]->loadHTMLFile($Path . '&start=' . $i);
        }
    }
    return $Docs;
}

function runParser($Path){
    $Result = '';
    foreach(initPagesToParse($Path) as $Doc) {
        $Result = $Result . getVoteIDsFromDocument($Doc);
    }
    if($Result == ''){
        return FALSE;
    }
    $FileID =  uniqid('Vote_IDs_', TRUE);
    if(file_put_contents ('VoteIDs_files/' . $FileID . '.txt', $Result, LOCK_EX) === FALSE){
        return FALSE;
    }
    return $FileID;
}
?>
```

parserMain.php:

```
<?php
include 'parserFunctions.php';

error_log("Parsing \n");

if(!isset($_POST["URL"]) || $_POST["URL"] == null) {
    echo 'REQ ERROR';
    exit();
}

$url = $_POST["URL"];

if(($FileID = runParser($url)) === FALSE){
    echo 'PARSING ERROR';
    exit();
}

error_log($url);
error_log($FileID);
echo $FileID;
?>
```

And to get this string I have a html page with a javascript that use a XMLHttpRequest to get the result.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
"use strict";
function sendUrlToParser() {
    var handleResponse = function (status, response) {
        alert(response);
    }

    var handleStateChange = function () {
        switch (xmlhttp.readyState) {
            case 0 : // UNINITIALIZED
            case 1 : // LOADING
            case 2 : // LOADED
            case 3 : // INTERACTIVE
                break;
            case 4 : // COMPLETED
                handleResponse(xmlhttp.status, xmlhttp.responseText);
                break;
            default: alert("error");
        }
    }

    var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = handleStateChange;
    xmlhttp.open("POST", "parserMain.php", true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlhttp.send("URL=" + document.getElementById("URL").value);
}
</script>
```

When I use this script to get the result of my php script, in asynchronus mode (true) I get a status == 0 and I get an empty response while in synchronus mode (false) I get a status == 200 and I can display my result.

After several test I have noticed that is only when I use the parser that my asynchronous request stops working. If the php script stops before the runParser (in case of non-existent variable for example) I can get an answer (REQ ERROR in this case).

Is my problem related to the use of DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile or is the problem elsewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved by disabling page refresh after a request.
Adding a "return false;" in the "onsubmit" attribute.

```
<form method="POST" onsubmit="sendUrlToParser(); return false;">
```